# Storing your local IP in an environment variable with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ip, environment-variables

I am trying to store my local ip into a system variable but I am struggling with that batch file. I am already able to parse my IP and extract the right substring. However declaring the variable and passing it to SETX seems to be harder than I thought....

Any help would be very much appreciated. :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::just a sample adapter here:
set "adapter=Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network"
set adapterfound=false
echo Network Connection Test
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig /all`) do (
    set "item=%%f"
    if /i "!item!"=="!adapter!" (
        set adapterfound=true
    ) else if not "!item!"=="!item:IPv4-Address=!" if "!adapterfound!"=="true" (
        echo %%g | cut -d"(" -f 1 | tr -d "[:space:]"       <-- this echos my ip correctly
        set ipadress=%%g | cut -d"(" -f 1 | tr -d "[:space:]"
        echo %ipadress%                                     <-- this echos empty string
        setx MY_IP %ipadress%                               <-- this doesnt work as well
        set adapterfound=false
    )
)
```

Comment: You are aware of `enabledelayedexpansion`. Then, use `!ipadress!` instead of `%ipadress%`.

Comment: !ipadress! gives me a syntax error

Comment: Do you need the exact ipv4 address associated with this specific adapter or just your prefered local ip address?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the exact adapter. But this is working already. I just want to jam the String result of "%%g | cut -d"(" -f 1 | tr -d "[:space:]"" into a variable and then pass it to the setx command.

Answer (score 0):

Improved script (might be locale-dependent):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
::just a sample adapter here:
set "adapter=Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network"
set "adapterfound=false"
echo Network Connection Test
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig /all`) do (
    set "item=%%f"
    if not "!item!"=="!item:%adapter%=!" (
        set "adapterfound=true"
        echo %adapter%
    ) else if not "!item!"=="!item:IPv4 Address=!" if "!adapterfound!"=="true" (
           rem                     ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ might be locale-dependent
        for /F "delims=( " %%G in ("%%g") do set "ipadress=%%G"
        echo !ipadress!
        rem setx MY_IP !ipadress!
        set "adapterfound=false"
    )
)
echo %ipadress%
```

Another approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:: just a sample adapter here:
set "adapter=Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network"
echo Network Connection Test
:: get adapter index
set "_where=where "NetConnectionID = '%adapter%'""
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter %_where% get InterfaceIndex /value ^| findstr "="
') do for /F %%g in ("%%H") do set "_ii=%%~g" 
:: get adapter's IP addresses
set "_where=where "InterfaceIndex = '%_ii%'""
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('
wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration %_where% get IPAddress /value ^| findstr "="
') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims={,}" %%g in ("%%H") do (
        set "_IPv4=%%~g" 
        set "_IPv6=%%~h"
      )
set _ip
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the desired value;
- `%%g` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)